# Where does CEPS fall on the political spectrum?

Tags: european-union, political-spectrum

I am curious about the general political leanings of [CEPS](https://www.ceps.eu/).

Answer (score 2):

> Where does CEPS fall on the political spectrum?

The Centre for European Policy Studies (CEPS) "favours European integration," but otherwise claims to be neutral, and allows that its researchers may have "differing opinions on many issues."

[CEPS Integrity Statement](https://www.ceps.eu/about-ceps/ceps-integrity-statement/).

> **Institutional independence**
>
> CEPS’ commitment to independence is rooted in the individual integrity of its researchers, the diversity of its funding sources and its independence policy, which is supervised by a high-level Board of independent directors.
>
> CEPS does not have an institutional position. It encourages open, evidence-based, balanced discussion and competing ideas, both internally and with external stakeholders and policymakers. The opinion of CEPS fellows does not engage the institution: indeed, differing opinions on many issues among CEPS researchers are not unusual.
>
> The core mission of CEPS is to carry out state-of-the-art policy-oriented research, addressing the challenges facing Europe. CEPS fellows are encouraged to participate in public debate. In doing so, they commit to avoiding any national, regional, sectoral, institutional or other bias or partisanship in their publications and contributions to the broader public debate.
>
> CEPS fellows do not shy away from taking a critical stance, where they deem it appropriate, towards the policy actions of national governments and European Union institutions. CEPS favours European integration, but has no presumption that more integration is always the best answer to Europe’s problems.